# Hash URL parameter, MD5 Hash (PHP)

Tags: php, javascript, hash, md5

I use ajax to submit value to the server.

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "services.php",
data: "a=1&b=2&c=3&d=4",
success: function(msg)
{
}
});
```

I face one problem. As you know, an experienced user can easily change the passing parameter value by keying following url in the browser url bar.

Eg: mywebsite.com/services.php?a=0&b=0&c=0&d=0

As far as I know, hashing (parameter +secret key) in Javascript. Then, I pass the parameter value together with hashed value to the server. Hashing(parameter +secret key) is done in php script. If both hashed values matches, it will update data in the database.

Basically,

In javascript: sort(parameter) -> join(parameter) -> md5(parameter)
In php script: sort(parameter) -> join(parameter) -> md5(parameter) -> compare both hashed values

Is there any suitable way to prevent it from being changed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should just validate the parameters and their values server-side

Comment: If this some sort of operation that should be allowed only for authorized users? If so use a cookie-session-variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is how do you keep the secret key hidden from the user in the javascript? If you expose it, the user can still make changes and just rehash the parameters. You can't really prevent this sort of modification, which is why you need to sanitize and validate all the input on the server side.

Comment: You are right. Is there any suitable way to prevent parameter values from being changed?

Comment: Not really. Think of it this way. The user can send any arbitrary data at your server, so you will never be able to control the input you get from your web client (after all, data might not always come from a client). To protect against this, you _must_ do validation on the server side. Users can manipulate anything and everything on the client side.

Comment: For your information, param values are generated in the client side. For example, a quiz website. Quiz result is generated in the client side. Is there any way to prevent quiz result from being changed when submitting it to the server? Data integrity?